# Add missing node in XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML nodes as follows:

```
<AA title="xx">
   <BB/>
   <AA><title>yy</title></AA>
   <AA title="zz"></AA>
</AA>
```

`title` inside `AA` nodes is sometimes an attribute and sometimes it is a child node. I need to have it all fitted into a node. That means if the title node is missing I need to create one and copy the value from the attribute.

How do I do it using XSL? I tried to use this but it does not work:

```
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AA">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:if test="not(/title)">
          <title><xsl:valueOf select="@title"/></title>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: The error message is "'xsl:valueOf' cannot be a child of the 'title' element.".

Comment: What, exactly, does "does not work" mean?  What does it do? Do you see any errors?  Have you tried fixing any errors reported by your XSL processor?  What happens once you've fixed them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xsl:valueOf` is not XSL. Replace it by `xsl:value-of`.

Then the transformation will work in principle, but you end up with duplicate  definitions. To remove the duplicates, change `not(/title)` to `not(./title)`.

Here's my complete transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xml:space="default" exclude-result-prefixes="" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="AA">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="not(./title)">
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
        </title>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get the following error: [xslt] addtitle.xsl:32: Fatal Error! An attribu te node (class) cannot be created after the children of the containing element [xslt]

Comment: @user1749707: I'm using .NET 2.0 with the XslTransform class. If you use a different technology, maybe you want to repost your question, specify the technology (use tags) and give us parts of your source code.

Comment: Got it. I moved  <xsl:apply-template...> before <xsl:if... and now it work... Thank you very much